# How can i play recorded adobe connect session?

Tags: adobe, adobe-connect

I downloaded session record by adding /output/recording.zip?download=zip at the end of the recording URL. Record folder has some .flv and .xml files. How can i play this session? Am i use flv editor?

Answer (score 1):

The recording you download using /output/recording.zip?download=zip query is not the video, it contains form FLV but they will not play.

To play the recording make the recording offline, in Adobe Connect 9 there is an option on recording page "Make Flv" under Actions tab.

You will have to play complete recording to download.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you'll need to use an editor for that.
Usually the way to download an Adobe Connect recording is the one described in the [official documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/connect/8.0/using/WS20F14479-39A1-42e2-AF0A-F8C2F1AA9BE4.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should only use flv files, not xml files
**cameraVoip.flv** file for microphone, camera video and **screenshare.flv** for shared screen (from desktop).
You can also get the start time of these files in the indexstream.xml file, if you know how to work with ffmpeg software or other software, you can combine these files.
But if you can not and only audio and video are important to you and not a text conversation, you can use the program I wrote.

**It goes without saying that Adobe Connect files may be corrupted for any reason, so make sure they are safe and then work with Adobe files.**

https://github.com/HosseinShams00/AdobeConnectDownloader

Comment: how should we run and use this program?

Comment: @Soroosh 
hi you can go to [this address](https://github.com/HosseinShams00/AdobeConnectDownloader/releases) and download last version of program and run it on your windows devices